# Losing first record and the values keep changing when loading reader to datatable

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datatable, datareader

I load reader to my table like this

```
                  connection.Open();
                    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
                    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sqlReader.Read();
                    dt.Load(sqlReader);
```

But it looks like I cannot retrieve the first record of fetch data.
The second problem is when I call the reader several times after that:

```
                    string comName = dt.Rows[0]["companyName"].ToString();

                        //To get address
                        sqlCmd.CommandText = addr;
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", comName);
                        using (var addressReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (addressReader.Read())
                            {
                                Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + addressReader["address"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        //To get keyProcesses
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        sqlCmd.CommandText = keyProcesses;
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", comName);
                        using (var keyProcessesReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (keyProcessesReader.Read())
                            {
                                Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + keyProcessesReader.GetString(0);
                            }
                        }
```

But I find out that these reading also may changes the value of my datatable dt above! How could I only load data to dt at the first reading and keep it there without changing any more ?

Ps: In attempt to overcome the second problem, I am trying to store dt values in list

```
 public class CompanyModel
    {
        public string compnName { get; set; }
        public string compnAddress { get; set; }
        public string compnKeyProcesses { get; set; }
        public string compnStandards { get; set; }
    }
```

then

```
 List<CompanyModel> companies = new List<CompanyModel>();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            companies.Add(new CompanyModel 
                            { 
                                compnName =  dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString(),
                                compnAddress =  dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString()
                            });
                        }

                        companyRepeater.DataSource = companies;
                        companyRepeater.DataBind();
```

Now, how do I access each company name in the list to make query on that name value accordingly, then input the new result to the list?
I tried:

```
foreach(List<Component> compnName in companies.Contains("companyName")
                        {

                            sqlCmd.CommandText = getKey;
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", compnName);
                            using (var keyReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (keyReader.Read())
                                {
                                   companies.Add(new CompanyModel compnKeyProcesses =  keyReader.GetString("key"));
                                }
                            }

                            sqlCmd.CommandText = getstandard;
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("companyName", compnName);
                            using (var standardReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (standardReader.Read())
                                {
                                   companies.Add(new CompanyModel compnStandards =  keyReader.GetString("standards"));
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your first problem

```
SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
            DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            sdr.Fill(dt);
```

you can display this whole data as a matter of confirmation by taking a datagridview

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: what is the different of adapter with my method? Or the fill command is better than the load command?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It fixed the first issue! Have any reason for it ?Btw, for the second problem, I am using list. I update in my question. But I don't know how could I access each companyName in the list by the same order everytime?